# Updating row directly in ASP.NET using databind() ! Please help me

Tags: asp.net, gridview, void, protected, sender

This is a difficult problem so I found how to solve when cell on table don't receive input value from user . Please show me how retrieve value from updated cell  . Please help me . I am very boring because of seeing this problem

```
protected void GridView1_RowUpdating(object sender, GridViewUpdateEventArgs e)
{
    int id;

    id = int.Parse(GridView1.DataKeys[e.RowIndex].Value.ToString());

    foreach (GridViewRow row in GridView1.Rows)
    {
        value1 = row.Cells[2].Text;//Only receive lastest value . Cann't receive value when it is updated
    }

    //Response.Write("Check value" + value1);
    DataClassesCheckDataContext ctx = new DataClassesCheckDataContext();
    ctx.EditStudentProc(id, value1);
    GridView1.DataSource = ctx.Students;
    GridView1.EditIndex = -1;
    GridView1.DataBind();
}
```

Comment: Why are you looping through every row in your table when e.RowIndex tells you which row was updated?  Why are you re-binding your data on every update event?

Comment: looping use to try finding value of cell and databind() to load immediately after activing

Answer (score 0):

On RowUpdating the updated values are in e.NewValues, Ref http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.gridviewupdateeventargs.newvalues.aspx

Comment: I gave up rowupdating and using tool . It helps me easily